# Why is the Ethereum Virtual Machine designed as a stack based language?

Tags: solidity, evm, ethereum-design, ewasm, wasm

I heard that Ethereum is about to change into a flavor of Web Assembly (a register-based language, eWASM).
Web Assembly is register-based, which means they are faster.

So why is Ethereum using a stack-based language so far?
What advantage does it have being based on a stack-based language or
are there any other special reasons?

Comment: Here you can find an answer [`A Prehistory of the Ethereum Protocol
`](http://vitalik.ca/general/2017/09/14/prehistory.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stack-based machine can be easier to implement than a register-based one, and I assume that was ultimately the decision-making factor here. The document "A Prehistory of the Ethereum Protocol" linked above hints at that.

**WebAssembly is also stack-based**, however the assembly is designed to be **structured**: blocks are explicitly terminated by an END instruction that trigger a stack clean-up. That makes the translation to register-based relatively straight-forward. That is not the case with the EVM: the stack is global, there is no such concept of code-block, and stack discrepancies can be introduced, sometimes voluntarily (compiler optimizations, etc.).